# When will Seam 3 be out?

Tags: seam, seam3

Does anybody know when Seam 3 will officially be out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea what Seam 3 is, but I can use Google. [The timeline for Seam 3](http://in.relation.to/Bloggers/TheTimelineForSeam3):

> We are aiming to have development finished by mid June, spend a month polishing up the documentation and examples, and **have a release candidate ready for you to try out in mid July**.

From the [transcript](http://seamframework.org/Seam3/MeetingTranscript20100415):

> [15:49:27] < pmuir> and we should aim to have a CR1 of the distribution out on 15th July
>   [15:50:08] < pmuir> we'll follow the standard pattern from then of doing a CR every 3-4 weeks until there are no critical issues being reported
>   [15:50:27] < pmuir> in general I would expect to do CR1 and CR2 for Seam, follow by a Final release a couple of weeks after CR2

Comment: +1 for `I have no idea what Seam 3 is, but I can use Google` - simply brilliant!